Can telegraf take data that contains spaces?
I have telegraf running and the data that I am receiving from sensors contains spaces. Eg. SOX= 0x0000000 0xa1aaaa1a. I cannot find a way to input the data with the spaces in so I can parse the string later.
I have tried the http_v2_listener with both the value and form urlencoded data types and I have not had any luck.

You could use the starlark or regex plugins to replace the space with an underscore, and send that on to Influx as a String field value.
Later on, in your processing, you can remove the underscore and extract the values as and when either in Flux or SQL - depending on what you want to do with it.
